# Java - Arraylist contents to display in Jtable

Tags: java, arraylist, jtable

I am working on a project and I am stuck on this area. I am reading text from a file and I am saving it into an arraylist. the problem is the content from the file appears in one line of text in the jtable but i want each line to be displayed in rows. I am passing the data from another class and I know this is working because I can see the contents printed out in the console row after row . I have tried a few different ways but I've run out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

Below is the code I have wrote.

```
for (String item : helper.getItems() )
{       
    System.out.println(item);
    storage.add(item);
}

    JTable t1 = new JTable();
    t1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                    {storage.toString()}    
            },
            new String[]{
                    "Tool Equipment"
            }

    ));
```

Comment: You have a loop that adds the data to an ArrayList. Why are you doing that first? You can just use the DefaultTableModel.addRow(..) method to add the data directly to the model, so there is no need for an ArrayList.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i dont really understand what you are saying. can i not use an arraylist to display the text in the jtable?

Comment: No, the data needs to be added to a TableModel.

Comment: so i add the the item to the tablemodel inside the for loop and then just set the model to that for the table?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? I hope you didn't wait 4 hours for me to respond to your question.;

Comment: oh i did ya because i have nothing better for doing! :P   and when i run it gave me a null pointer exception error.

Comment: it's okay. i got it working. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

`storage.toString()` will give you string representation of your `ArrayList`. What you want is probably `List#toArray`

Comment: Thanks for replying, So are you saying to put the storage.toArray() because I have tried that and I dont get anything when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add items to a `JTable` using the `DefaultTableModel` object is to utilize the `.addRow` method of the `DefaulTableModel`.  You'll need to parse the `storage` string to deliminate the values you want placed into each row/col

For Example:

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
// parsing of the storage obj, to get individual values for each col/row
// depending on the structure of storage a looping construct would be beneficial here
String col1= storage.substring(startindex, endindex);
String col2=storage.substring(startindex, endindex);
//add items to the model in a new row
model.addRow(new Object[] {col1, col2});
// if you used a loop to parse the data in storage, end it here
// add model to the table
t1.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Im not too sure how I would use the startindex and endindex for what I want to do?